# How to count the empty cells above specific values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is going to be an odd request, apologies! I would like to be able to count the number of blank cells that are directly above a "Banana" cell. This only needs to happen in one column. In the example below, the number 2 should be returned, because there are 2 blank cells right above a banana cell. I bolded those 2 blank cells. Let me know if you have an idea for counting this!

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Banana |
| 3 | ***(blank)*** |
| 4 | Banana |
| 5 | *(blank)* |
| 6 | Apple |
| 7 | *(blank)* |
| 8 | ***(blank)*** |
| 9 | Banana |

I'm imagining a sumproduct/index/match formula, but at a bit of a loss for how exactly to accomplish this. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SUM()` & `IF()`

[image]

---

```
=SUM(IFNA(IF(DROP(A1:A9,1)="Banana",IF(A1:A9="",1,0)),0))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(IFNA((DROP(A1:A9,1)="Banana")*(A1:A9=""),0))
```

---

- Using `DROP()` function, excluding the first row.
- Next doing a `Boolean Logic` to verify if its equal to `Banana`
- Using another `IF()` to verify if its empty or not.
- If the condition matches then return `1` else `0`.
- Lastly, using the `SUM()` function to sum the whole array.

---

Breakdown of formulas:

[image]

---

All the above methods shown is one single input, however, if one has access to `LET()` function then it makes easier for readability.

```
=LET(α, A1:A9, SUM(IFNA((DROP(α,1)="Banana")*(α=""),0)))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `A1:A9` use the simple formula:

```
=SUM((A2:A9="Banana")*(A1:A8=""))
```